# powershell replace entire value if character exists

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

would need assistance on my Powershell task.

Im working on updating a column value in a csv file based on a reference table in a different csv file. For example, below is how the table is laid out;

**file1**

environment | team

storage prod, (empty)

storage test, (empty)

master prod, (empty)

master mds, (empty)

**file2**

environment | team

storage, geodata

master, fsd

**desired file output**

environment | team

storage prod, geodata

storage test, geodata

master prod, fsd

master mds, fsd

Atm, my current method is only replacing the first character, but the character that follows remains. Example; storage prod, geodata prod. Please assist.

This is my working,

```
foreach ($team1 in $report){
$matched = $false
    foreach ($team2 in $reference){
    $obj = "" | select "Team","Environment"
    if(($team1.'Environment') -eq ($team2.'Environment'){
        $matchCounter++
        $matched = $true
        $obj.'Team' = $team2.'Team'
        $obj.'Environment' = $team1.'Environment'
        $obj | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Output" -Append -NoTypeInformation
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the data from file1, then loop over the rows in file2 and where there is a match found in the `environment` column, update the data with the value of `team` like below:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\file1.csv'
foreach ($row in (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\file2.csv')) {
    $data | Where-Object { $_.environment -match [regex]::Escape($row.environment) } | 
            ForEach-Object {  $_.team = $row.team }
}

# show on screen
$data | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to new csv
$data | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Output\combinedData.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Using `[regex]::Escape($row.environment)` is not needed in your example data, but in real life, that value could contain characters that have special meaning in regex (`-match` uses regex).
If you don't want to use regular expressions, the same can be achieved with
`Where-Object { $_.environment -like "*$($row.environment)*" }`

Output on screen:

```
environment  team   
-----------  ----   
storage prod geodata
storage test geodata
master prod  fsd    
master mds   fsd
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up from this, forgot to mention that perhaps some of the cells in file1 might not match with file2. Therefore need help for this as well. For example,

```
file1 

environment  team   
-----------  ----   
wgs prod 
wgs test 

file2

environment  team   
-----------  ----   
(no wgs's team reference)
```

So instead I would like go through each row, and have the existed one replace, then as one with no reference, will simply have empty cell. The output then look something like this;

```
environment  team   
-----------  ----   
storage prod geodata
storage test geodata
wgs prod
wgs test
master prod  fsd    
master mds   fsd
```